# Preview WIndow is not displaying in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Need Help For How to enable the[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdLtz.png) preview window in Android Studio

Comment: decrease the preview version to some lesser api lever like 20,19, it will work

Comment: Decrease the preview version or just do as directed, I mean - Just update your SDK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try changing android version while rendering layout

[image: Just try changing android version while rendering layout[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhRZp.png)

or otherwise update your sdk to recent version.

Answer (score 0):

You must install **version 24** sdk or you can downgrade its version specific version which you had install already

Comment: i am getting error while downloading  source-24 package

Answer (score -1):

In android studio you may find `preview` window under **View -> Tool Windows -> Preview**

Comment: It's a comment not an answer.